# Load Data when fragment is click/called

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, fragment

I have added 2 fragments in one activity, every time I open app data from both the fragments gets load which makes app slow. I want to call/show data when the fragment is clicked or Opened

Here is few code when I am calling fragments

```js
private void openCampus() {

        resetColor();
        frame.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        drawer.closeDrawers();
        Fragment fragment = new CampusFragment();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putInt(BUNDLE_LOAD_TYPE, tabLoadType);
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);

        openFragment(fragment);
    }
```

```js
 private void openFragment(Fragment selectedFragment) {

        if (selectedFragment != null) {
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, selectedFragment, CURRENT_TAG);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }
    }
```

Comment: what do you mean when you say app is slow? do you mean that the UI is not responsive when your fragments fetch data?

Comment: Lets say I open fragment A but data from both the Fragments are loaded which makes app little bit slow

Comment: Is your activity loading data for fragments ? You can try to load data in async method and observe result immediatly in fragments with LiveData to handle lifecycle binding